# Sending text in python selenium using javascript execute_script()

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, input, sendkeys

I have requirement of passing the lengthy text to input text field, I tried to use javascript and used below two approaches but none of them working, Could someone please help what could be the issue?

Solution 1:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('ck-tag')[0].value='" + data + "'")
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('ck-tag')[0].value='" + data + "';")
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('ck-tag')[0].value='data'")
```

None of the above line worked and text box is empty. In the dev console though "document.getElementsByClassName('ck-tag')[0]" returns proper element.

Solution 2:

```
    xpath = '//div[@aria-label="Rich Text Editor, main"]//p'
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    element.send_keys("Hello")
    # Above line works
    self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=" ' + data + ' " ;', element)
    self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=" ' + data + ' " ', element)
    # Both above line fails and does not enter any text.
```

Comment: Asked more than a year back and viewed 700 times but NO answers :(. Any suggestions on what I should do to get some answers.